# Access to port 80 from outside - Centos

Tags: centos, request, port

I am redirecting requests from port 6080 to port 80:

```
cd /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

<virtualHost *:80>
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass / http://localhost:6080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:6080/
</VirtualHost>
```

and I have port 80 open :

```
cd /etc/sysconfig/iptables

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2440:360634]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 6080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

and I checked with `netstat` to make sure it is listening.

When I use `wget localhost:80` and I got the index.html retrieved however when I try to get the  html from browser, I get:
 *"this webpage is not available".*

How can I access to this port from outside?

Comment: Did you really mean to open `udp` port 80 and 6080?

Comment: Also, and I don't do apache so I could certainly be wrong here but, isn't that vhost redirecting *from* 80 *to* 6080?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Port 80 is suppose to be TCP (not UDP) so change to:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Remove the line below because it is doesn't help and is covered by the rule above:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Do you really want port 6080 exposed to the outside world?If not remove

```
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 6080 -j ACCEPT
```

I should point out that removing this line probably won't hurt anything because it too was specified as using `UDP` and not `TCP`. If you did want it exposed to the outside world then you'll have to change it too. Generally when you do proxying internally behind a firewall you don't intend to expose the internal port so I would be very suspicious. If for some reason beyond my ability to understand you really do need to expose it too then you'll have to change the port 6080 line to:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 6080 -j ACCEPT
```

I believe it should look like this:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2440:360634]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing '--state NEW' on the line where you open port 80.